# Need to change from get ByID to ClassName (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

It is working when I do this with getElementByID. But when I change it to className, it doesn't work.

The reason why I am going to do this with class name is because there would be many looping (php) ticket in the page which is ordered by ticket number. And when "view" is clicked for a specif ticket, it will show the full message on it.

Of course, I can't get it by multiple duplicate "id" here. And I need to change it to class name only. Help, please.

```
            <div id="menuTiket">
                <span style="padding:10px; background:yellow; float:right;">
                    <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementsByClassName('light').style.display='block'; 
                                                             document.getElementsByClassName('fade').style.display='block';
                                                             ">Tiket Baru</a></span></div>

                    <!--Black Overlay-->    
                    <div id="fade" class="fade overlayMessage" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>                                        

                    <!--Pop Up Div-->   
                    <div id="light" class="light popupBoxMesage">                      

                            <span style="position: absolute; top: 11px; right:1px; color:white;" id="closeBlocked">
                                <a style="color:green; text-decoration:none; background:white; padding:10px;" href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick ="document.getElementsByClassName('light').style.display='none'; document.getElementsByClassName('fade').style.display='none'"><b> X </b></a>
                            </span>
                        </div>
```

CSS:

```
    <style type="text/css">

            .overlayMessage{
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0%;
                left: 0%;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background-color: black;
                z-index:10000001;
                -moz-opacity: 0.5;
                opacity:.45;
                filter: alpha(opacity=40);
            }

            .popupBoxMesage {
                display: none;
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                bottom:0;
                right:0;
                border: solid 10px darkseagreen;
                background-color: greenyellow;
                width:70%;
                height:400px;
                z-index:10000002;
                overflow: auto;
                padding: 1% 2% 12px 2%;
                margin: auto;
            }
            /* CSS Document */
    </style>
```

Comment: It's `getElement**s**ByClassName`not `getElementByClassName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `getElementsByClassName`(notice the 's' after 'Element') because it returns more than one element. You can have multiple elements in the DOM with the same class.

The result will be a collection, and you can see a specific item like so :

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
var firstElement = elements[0];
```

Comment: Have you added the `[0]` (to target the first element, replace it by the proper index) ? Even if you only have one matching element (with that class), you still need to include it.

Comment: how to do that in this code: `onclick ="document.getElementsByClassName('light')`?

Comment: Simply add the `[0]` after the closing parenthesis, like so `onclick ="document.getElementsByClassName('light')[0]`

Comment: +1 it is working. But why `<div id="fade" class="fade overlayMessage" onLoad="initDynamicOptionLists()"></div>` doesn't close when I close it? I have done the same to all of them?

Comment: I forgot the 's' again. :) Thank you for helping me, friend.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do this inside `echo '--content---';` ?

I got an error in the javascript function.

Comment: What is content and where are you trying to echo it? It's PHP code?

Comment: Yes it is php Like this `echo '<span><a href = "javascript:void(0)" 
                                                     onclick ="document.getElementsByClassName(\'lightMessageTicket\')[0].style.display="block"; 
                                                     document.getElementsByClassName(\'fadeMessageTicket\')[0].style.display="block"">
                                                     View</a>
                                    </span>';`

Comment: What error message do you get? Have you tried to put your code in a function and call that function with your onclick event? This might help prevent errors with ' and ", although you seemed to have escaped them properly.

Comment: With this I got no error anymore by using `(\'className\')`, but it just don't pop up the div when I click it.